# How to fix error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'concat')?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add localStorage to my Todo on React, but I getting an error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'concat') when I try to add new todo item. How to fix it? Here my code:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import TodoInput from './TodoInput';
import TodoList from './TodoList';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState('');
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const localStorage = window.localStorage;
  const [localTodos, setLocalTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLocalTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')));
  }, []);

  function addTodo() {
    if (todo !== '') {
      setLocalTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')));
      localTodos = localTodos.concat([todo]);
      localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(localTodos));
      setTodo('');
    }
  };

  function deleteTodo(text) {
    localTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));

    localTodos = localTodos.filter((todo) => {
      return todo !== text;
    });

    setLocalTodos(localTodos);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Your todos</h1>
      <TodoInput todo={todo} setTodo={setTodo} addTodo={addTodo} />
      <TodoList list={localTodos} remove={deleteTodo} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot mutate the state this way:

```js
localTodos = localTodos.concat([todo]); // <-- wrong approach
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(localTodos));
```

You have to create a copy of the state so you can update this latter and then use it

```js
let copyLocalTodos = [...localTodos]
copyLocalTodos = copyLocalTodos.concat([todo]);
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(copyLocalTodos));
```

You have to make those changes in both your `deleteTodo` and `addTodo` functions

---

2. setState is asynchronous

```js
setLocalTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')));
localTodos = localTodos.concat([todo]); // don't expect the state to be updated here cause `setState` is async
```

---

Also you can initilize your state with the value from localstorage

```
const [localTodos, setLocalTodos] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot more to the problem than just that one error:

1. You're trying to manually over-write a state value, which is entirely wrong.
2. You're trying to read the updated state value [before it's actually been updated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/328193).

Also, consider this approach logically.  You *just queued an update* to that state value on the immediate previous line.  If you want to update state to a concatenated value, *first* concatenate the value and *then* update state.

For example:

```
function addTodo() {
  if (todo !== '') {
    let newTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    newTodos = newTodos.concat([todo]);
    setLocalTodos(newTodos);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
    setTodo('');
  }
};
```

Don't forget to also update the call to `setItem` to use the `newTodos` value, since `localTodos` won't have been updated yet at that time.